# Fetching data in onResume doubling the data in android?

Tags: android

I have a fragment where the `onCreateView` method sends a request to a server and fetches some data. This is working fine but when I send another request in `onResume`, it doubles the data in the listview. How can I fix this problem?

**Code:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_listing, container, false);//intialize mainLayout
    getDetails();// get deatail of user from sharedpreference......
    init();//initialize metho
    return m_Main;
}

private void getDetails() {// get details of user from shared preference...
    CLoginSessionManagement m_oSessionManagement = new CLoginSessionManagement(getActivity());// crating object of Login Session
    HashMap<String, String> user = m_oSessionManagement.getLoginDetails();// get String from Login Session
    m_szMobileNumber = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_MOBILE).trim();// getting password from saved preferences..........
    m_szEncryptedPassword = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_PASSWORD).trim();// getting mobile num from shared preferences...
    sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// increment of record count
    sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// increment of last count...

    s_oDataset = new ArrayList<>();// making object of Arraylist

    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        postDealListingDatatoServer();// here sending request in onCreate
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        postDealListingDatatoServer();// here in on Resume send request which double data

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void init() {// initialize controls

    m_ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);// finding Id of progressview
    m_ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);// make profressView Invisible first time

    /*Swipe to refresh code*/
    mSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    mSwipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh_progress_1);

    mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            /*Here check net connection avialable or not */
            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {

                m_ListView.removeFooterView(btnLoadMore);
                s_oDataset.clear();
                m_n_DeafalutLastCount = 0;
                sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                swipeData();


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (mSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {

                    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    m_n_FormImage = new int[]{// defining Images in Integer array
            R.drawable.amazon,
            R.drawable.whatsapp,
            R.drawable.zorpia,
            R.drawable.path,
            R.drawable.app_me,
            R.drawable.evernote,
            R.drawable.app_me};

    m_ListView = (ListView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.dealList);// findind Id of Listview
    m_ListView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    m_ListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (firstVisibleItem == 0) {
                mSwipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mSwipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });


}

    /*This is new changes in code ....using Volley instead of AsynkTask*/

/*This method send request to server for deallisting*/
// this method send request to server for deal list....
public void postDealListingDatatoServer() {
    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string

        System.out.println("Request:-" + json);
        m_Dialog = DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(getActivity(), "Please wait while loading deals...");
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, CServerAPI.m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println("Response:-" + response);
                m_Dialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from response
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                        item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                        item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                        item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// get dealcode from response
                        item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));// get deal value from response
                        item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);//set Image Index wise(Dummy)
                        s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

                    }

                    // LoadMore button
                    btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());// creating button
                    btnLoadMore.setText("LOAD MORE DEALS");// set Text in Button
                    btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_boarder);// set Background Resource
                    btnLoadMore.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                    btnLoadMore.setTextSize(14);
                    btnLoadMore.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);// set Color of button text
                    btnLoadMore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);// set Gravity of button text


                    if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {// condition if data in arraylist is not empty
                        // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
                        m_ListView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);// add footer in listview
                        m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                        m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
                    } else {
                        btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);// else Load buttonvisibility set to Gone
                    }
                    btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {// load more button onclick listener
                            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                                m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                                m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above
                                String itemscount = String.valueOf(m_ListView.getAdapter().getCount());
                                System.out.println("Toatal item:-" + itemscount);

                                sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                                sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                                loadmoreData();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());

                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Technical Failure")) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Technical Failure", getActivity());
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Errror:-" + error);
                m_Dialog.dismiss();
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection lost ! Please try again", getActivity());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No internet connection", getActivity());
                }

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: postDealListingDatatoServer(); method is inside getDetails method and you called the getDetails method at onCreateView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear `s_oDataset` before adding the new data to it.

You could do something like this:

```
JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from response
s_oDataset.clear(); // clear the old values
for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
    JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
    item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
    item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
    item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// get dealcode from response
    item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));// get deal value from response
    item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);//set Image Index wise(Dummy)
    s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList
}
```

To prevent your `Button` from being doubled, instead of this:

```
m_ListView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
```

You could check if your `ListView` has a `FooterView` and create your `Button` accordingly:

```
if(m_ListView.getFooterViewsCount() == 0) {
    btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());// creating button
    btnLoadMore.setText("LOAD MORE DEALS");// set Text in Button
    btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_boarder);// set Background Resource
    btnLoadMore.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    btnLoadMore.setTextSize(14);
    btnLoadMore.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);// set Color of button text
    btnLoadMore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    m_ListView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove calling getDetails() from onCreateView which is calling postDealListingDatatoServer(). Call getDetails() method from onResume

You can remove if-else block which is in onResume() now and just call getDetails() from onResume

one more way is, clear s_oDataset before calling postDealListingDatatoServer(), this will avoid adding same data to the list

Answer (score 0):

onResume() is always called after onCreate() so no reason to have them do the same thing. Just implement onResume to call the data updating code not the onCreate()

Comment: I can't go thru your code properly at this time. My point is just that you have to design your code in a way that whatever is supposed to be called only once per activity should be implemented in onCreate() and whatever is supposed to be updated each time user enters your activity should be implemented in onResume(). Also make sure that whatever is implemented in onResume() clears out previous data otherwise if user leaves and comes back to your activity twice you will have the problem again.